# Why add a version number with CMake when it can be done with git?

Tags: c++, git, cmake, build, version-control

In [CMake's Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/guide/tutorial/#adding-a-version-number-and-configured-header-file), under the section "Adding a Version Number and Configured Header File", it explains how to add a version number to a project.

Why do this with CMake when version-control tools (such as git) already allow you to specify a version number?

What, if anything, is to be gained from specifying a project's version number in CMake as well as git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, that [same section of the tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/guide/tutorial/#adding-a-version-number-and-configured-header-file) has the answer. This is embarrassing!

Basically, CMake lets you substitute your version number into your code at build-time (essentially a macro), which git doesn't.

Comment: Good point; however CMake could call git to get the version number (e.g. something around `git describe` to get a tag) and then use the exact same technique in the tutorial to substitute that into source code.